# Image alignment not done correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am doing a two views application and I am  encountering an issue with a button and a table view not alligning the right way.

In the storyboard it looks correctly but in the simulator the send button doesn't appear and the tableview is showing with a space before.

I am running all my tests on the iPhone 5,5s simulator on xcode 6 beta 4 and I am attaching the photo for better understanding[image]

Comment: did you add missing constraints?

Comment: Use AutoLayout in storyboard and set Top layout and bottom layout guide for inner views. Also add constraints for alignment of all inner views.

Comment: Constraints were the answer.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Constraints

mainstoryboard 
click on your view then

right bottom you see |-/-| ... // /\ is triangle

click on it and select add missing contraints

Comment: Thank you very much.I didn;t know anything about constraints before.